# Как правильно составить зависимости моделей в Django?

Tags: django-admin, django

Доброго времени суток!

Господа, не могу понять как правильно сделать модели. Пока читаешь книгу, все кажется простым, а как доходит до практики... но, не суть, к делу:

У отделений есть "окна". Допустим у отделения 101000, есть окно 04 и 11. Т.е. много окон к одному отделению.

С каждого такого окна поступают файлы. Т.е. много файлов к одному окну.

Написал так:

```
# Отделение
class Ops(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=6, verbose_name='номер', unique=True)

# Окно
class Window(models.Model):
    ops = models.ForeignKey(Ops, verbose_name='ОПС')
    number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='номер')

# Файл
class RpoFile(models.Model):
    ops = models.ForeignKey(Ops, verbose_name='ОПС')
    window = models.ForeignKey(Window, verbose_name='окно')
    number = models.CharField(max_length=12, verbose_name='номер')
    date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='получен')
    records = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='записей')
    double = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='дубль')
    soft = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='софт')
```

Отделения добавляются на "ура", окна тоже, но вот при добавлении файла, когда я выбрал отделение, я могу выбрать любое окно, даже то, которое принадлежит другому отделению.

Подскажите дураку, в какую сторону копать? Как намертво привязать окно к отделению?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так чтоб не ломать стандартную админку, то никак.

Вопрос в другом - зачем ты файл привязываешь к отделению? Как по мне, то достаточно привязки файла к окну. Если тебе понадобится определить к какому отделению относится файл, то ты можешь это сделать через окно. Ну и наоборот, если понадобится выбрать все файлы конкретного отделения. Изучай queryset'ы, там много интересных приемов есть. Вообще следует исходить из конечных задач и продумывать оптимальную архитектуру связей.

Comment: А знаешь, ты прав. Спасибо за наводку. 
Я в принципе могу объединить отделение и окно.